# Sum of all rows of all columns - Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like this

```
1 4 7 ...
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

And I would like to have as output

```
6 15 24 ...
```

That is the sum of all the lines for all the columns. I know that to sum all the lines of a certain column (say column 1) you can do like this:

```
awk '{sum+=$1;}END{print $1}' infile > outfile
```

But I can't do it automatically for all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9 " \
| awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
   sums[i]+=$i;maxi=i}
 }
 END{
   for(i=1;i<=maxi;i++){
     printf("%s ", sums[i])
   }
 print}'
```

**output**

```
6 15 24
```

My recollection is that you can't rely on `for (i in sums)` to produce the keys any particular order, but maybe this is "fixed" in newer versions of gawk.

In case you're using an old-line Unix awk, this solution will keep your output in the same column order, regardless of how "wide" your file is.

IHTH

Comment: Instead of using maxi, you could just use NF :)

Comment: yes, tnx. The code could be significantly reduced in size, but my goal when writing answers is not the one-liner approach, but make it easier to understand for an awk beginner. (IMHO).

Comment: Thanks! I tried also using `for (i in sums)` but it gave me wrong results, instead in this way it works perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

One more awk

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=(a[i]+=$i)}END{print}' file
```

#### Output

```
6 15 24
```

#### Explanation

```
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)         Set field to 1 and increment through

$i=(a[i]+=$i)                Set the field to the sum + the value in field

END{print}                   Print the last line which now contains the sums
```

As with the other answers this will retain the order of the fields regardless of the number of them.

Comment: you wind the minimal awk code solution! Good luck to all.

Comment: There's an SO for code golf. I don't find "minimal" code helpful when you're actually trying to solve a problem, and it puzzles me that it's seen as a good thing in awk.

Comment: for some reason, this doesn't work on unix awk supplied with bsd. works using gawk (gnu awk) on these systems,

Answer (score 5):

You want to sum every column differently. Hence, you need an array, not a scalar:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=$i} END{for (i in sum) print sum[i]}' file
6
15
24
```

This stores `sum[column]` and finally prints it.

To have the output in the same line, use:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=$i} END{for (i in sum) printf "%d%s", sum[i], (i==NF?"\n":" ")}' file
6 15 24
```

This uses the trick `printf "%d%s", sum[i], (i==NF?"\n":" ")`: print the digit + a character. If we are in the last field, let this char be new line; otherwise, just a space.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple command called [`numsum`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/numsum.1.html) to do this:

```
numsum -c FileName

-c   ---    Print out the sum of each column.
```

**For example:**

```
cat FileName
1 4 7 
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

**Output :**

```
numsum -c FileName
6 15 24
```

**Note:**
If the command is not installed in your system, you can do it with this command:

```
apt-get install num-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

**AWK Program**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    print($0);
    len=split($0,a);
    if (maxlen < len) {
        maxlen=len;
    }
    for (i=1;i<=len;i++) {
        b[i]+=a[i];
    }
}

END {
    for (i=1;i<=maxlen;i++) {
        printf("%s ", b[i]);
    }
    print ""
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
3 6 9 12 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. It is just missed to print "sum". Try this:

```
awk '{sum+=$1;} END{print sum;}' infile > outfile
```