# Counting the number of lines in each column

Tags: awk, printing, wc

Is it possible to count the number of lines in each column of a file? For example, I've been trying to use awk to separate columns on the semi-colon symbol, specify each column individually and us wc command to count any and all occurrences within that column.
For the below command I am trying to find the number of items in column 3 without counting blank lines. Unfortunately, this command just counts the entire file. I could move the column to a different file and count that file but I just want to know if there is a much quicker way of going about this?

```
awk -F ';' '{print $3}' file.txt | wc -l
```

Data file format

```
; 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 ; 6 ;  
; 3 ; 4 ; 5 ; 6 ;   ; 4 ;  
;   ; 3 ; 5 ; 6 ; 9 ; 8 ;  
; 1 ; 6 ; 3 ;   ;   ; 4 ;  
; 2 ; 3 ;   ; 3 ;   ; 5 ;
```

Example output wanted

```
Column 1 = 4 aka(1 + 3 + 1 + 2)  
Column 2 = 5  
Column 3 = 4  
Colunm 4 = 4  
Column 5 = 2  
Column 6 = 5
```

Comment: hint: use an array using column number as index and then print the results in `END` block

Comment: here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104990/sum-of-all-rows-of-all-columns-bash - you just need to change how you count..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep separate counts for each field using an array, then print the totals when you're done:

```
$ awk -F' *; *' '{ for (i = 2; i < NF; ++i) if ($i != "") ++count[i] } 
  END { for (i = 2; i < NF; ++i) print "Column", i-1, "=", count[i] }' file
Column 1 = 4
Column 2 = 5
Column 3 = 4
Column 4 = 4
Column 5 = 2
Column 6 = 5
```

- Set the field separator to consume the semicolons as well as any surrounding spaces.
- Loop through each field (except the first and last ones, which are always empty) and increment a counter for non-empty fields.

  - it would be tempting to use `if ($i)` but this would fail for a column containing a `0`.
- Print the counts in the `END` block, offsetting by `-1` to start from `1` instead of `2`.

One assumption made here is that the number of columns in each line is uniform throughout the file, so that `NF` from the last line can safely be used in the `END` block.

---

A slight variation, using a simpler field separator:

```
$ awk -F';' '{ for (i = 2; i < NF; ++i) count[i] += ($i ~ /[^ ]/) } 
  END { for (i = 2; i < NF; ++i) print "Column", i-1, "=", count[i] }' file
```

`$i ~ /[^ ]/` is equal to `1` if any non-space characters exist in the `i`th field, `0` otherwise.

Comment: Nice solution, but I believe it could be a bit shorter if you do `count[i]+=($i != "")`

Comment: @kvantour thanks, I edited to add an alternative based on a similar principle.