# Print each column count alongwith header name

Tags: awk, count

I have a coma delemiated file. I am interested to count the number of rows (column count/length) in each column with their header name.

Example Dataset:

ID, IB, IM, IZ
0.05, 0.02, 0.01, 0.09
0.06, 0.01, ,     0.08
0.02, 0.06,

Coumn ID:3

Column IB:3

Column IM: 1

Column IZ:2

I have tried quite few option:

I can split these columns into seperate files and then can count number of lines in each file using wc -l File_name command.

This [Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360991/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-each-column) is very close to what I am interested in but stillunable to get header name. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
ID, IB, IM, IZ
0.05, 0.02, 0.01, 0.09
0.06, 0.01, , 0.08
0.02, 0.06,
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}NR==1{split($0,names);next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){counts[i]+=$i~/[^[:space:]]/}}END{for(i=1;i<=length(names);i+=1){print "Column",names[i]": "counts[i]}}' file.txt
```

output

```
Column ID: 3
Column  IB: 3
Column  IM: 1
Column  IZ: 2
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that `,` is field separator, when processing 1st record split whole lines (`$0`) into array `names`, so `ID` becomes `names[1]`,  `IB` becomes `names[2]`,  `IM` becomes `names[3]` and so on. After doing that go to `next` line. For all but 1st line iterate over columns using `for` loop, for every line increase value of `counts[i]` (where `i` is number of column) by *does that column contain non-whitespace character?* which is `0` for false and `1` for true. In other words increase by 1 if non-whitespace character found else increase by 0. After processing all lines iterate over `names` and print name with corresponding value of `counts`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Many thanks, how can we modify this script for tab-delimited file which parameter we need to change apart from FS= "\t" ?

Comment: @WaqasKhokhar it should work with just different `FS` (`split` use `FS` by default), though you might elect to change `print` if you wish space after `Column` rather than tab

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*' 'NR == 1 {header = $0; next} \
  {for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) n[i] += ($i ~ /\S/)} \
  END {$0 = header; for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print "Column " $i ": " n[i]}' file
Column ID: 3
Column IB: 3
Column IM: 2
Column IZ: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" *, *" }
NR == 1 {
    numCols = split($0,tags)
    next
}
{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( $i ~ /./ ) {
            cnt[i]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for ( i=1; i<=numCols; i++ ) {
        printf "Column %s:%d\n", tags[i], cnt[i]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Column ID:3
Column IB:3
Column IM:1
Column IZ:2
```